# Get position of segment in UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UISegmentedControl* control` with some segments. I want to get the position of a segment in the view. How do I get the position of a segment?

I'm looking for some option like this.

```
CGPoint position = [control getPositionOfSegmentAtIndex:5]
```

Comment: I would try getting the position of `[control.view.subviews objectAtIndex:5]`. The task looks rather suspicious, though: what are you planning to do with that position, anyway?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ehm.. suspicious ? :P I just want to make an animation end at that position. Xcode says that UISegmentControl doesn't have an property view

Comment: Sorry, I meant `[control.subviews objectAtIndex:5]` (segmented control *is* a view)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ah that works, thanks, little strange though as it seems like that the index is completely random, objectatindex:0 corresponds to index:10 objectatindex:1 corresponds to index:2

Comment: It's not too strange that the indexes are not mapping correctly, because my suggestion is a complete hack :)

Comment: What about adding up the widths of the preceding segments? See the `widthForSegmentAtIndex:` method.